# python listing mouse click coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7, click, mouseevent, onclicklistener

I would like to record and append to a list the x and y coordinates of limited number of mouse clicks (10 in this case (This will be a variable)). The script needs to record the clicks over the desktop, browsers or applications in general.

I am basically trying to create a list of coordinates for a flexible simple macro section of a larger program for desktop automation (Very simple and repetitive work but the layout does change that is why re-recording the coordinates is key).

I have searched through "Automate the boring stuff" and cant get pyautogui to record the positions (It does execute mouse positions perfectly but not the pre-recording list). Also this cannot be limited to a single frame as seems to be the case in pygame.

Im a noob any advice would be appreciated. I have included an image of the error I receive. The list portion is not included yet I will add that later.

```
from pynput import mouse

NumberOfMouseClicks = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(x, y)
    pynput.mouse.Listener.stop

while NumberOfMouseClicks < 10 :
    NumberOfMouseClicks = NumberOfMouseClicks + 1
    with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nO80.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not imported the `pynput` package only `mouse` from it.
So instead of

```
pynput.mouse.Listener.stop
```

you should use

```
mouse.Listener.stop
```

The mouse event is handled in the `on_click` function, the `while` loop is useless. You can use it so:

```
from pynput import mouse

class MyException(Exception):pass

NumberOfMouseClicks = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global NumberOfMouseClicks
    print(x, y)
    NumberOfMouseClicks = NumberOfMouseClicks + 1
    if (NumberOfMouseClicks==10):
        raise MyException(button)

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    try:
        listener.join()
    except MyException as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, its printing every click perfectly in the terminal but it still exceeds the "while loop statement" is less than 10, Seems like I am stuck in one instance of the listener and its not incrementing as I may have expected, will read up more now.

Comment: Yes, it is an other issue, the event is handled in the `on_click` function, so you should count there. I give an example in the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider upvoting the answer.